# React "Unexpected token" or not showing anything at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't even run a simple code! I've searched through the internet and tried almost everything!
I installed "npm" and included " type="text/babel" " in my "index.html" in the script tag.
It's just not working!

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <h1>
            Hello React
          </h1>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code that works and has a result:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>wtf</h1>,document.getElementById("App"))
```

Comment: Do you have the Babel standalone script in your page as well? (`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: Can you please show the file -probably _index.js_ - which containes the `React.DOM.render` call?

Comment: Did you try this?
```ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("App"))```

Comment: @Karan It works! But why?! Why can't I use Export?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to separate files, you should import your component and render it after:

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
 render() {
    return <h1>Hello React</h1>
  }
}
```

and

```
// index.js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; //means that App.js in the same folder as index.js

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("App"))
```

or just simply combine your files:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello React</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("App"));
```

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("App"))
This one works!
But why?! Why can't I use "export" ?!

Comment: @AidaRostami if you want to use export you should separate your components to different files. For example, App.js and index.js
Exporting/importing files is more easy to read though. I recommend you to read how to structure your react app

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a CDN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>YourApp</title>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

   <style>
   #container 
   {
     padding: 50px;
     background-color: #FFF;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class YourApp extends React.Component {
render() {

     return (
              <h1>hello react</h1>
            );
       }
  }

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     <YourApp/>
  </div>,
   document.querySelector("#container"));

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I recommend checking this out:
https://www.kirupa.com/react/

Comment: It´s not the most beautiful looking code but I´ve updated it so it should be copy pastable.

Comment: Thank you! But, can u tell me why I can't use "Export" ?

Comment: I´m not sure but I think it has something to do with the node.js environment. Perhaps you could try using Atom. https://atom.io/

Comment: Ok. thank u for the information and recommendation! I'm checking it out.

Comment: Sure, I´d love to help in any way I can ^^ Although in order to use the chat function we both need 20 in reputation ^^

Comment: So, I really don't know how can I contact with u! It's my Instagram "rostami_aida" at least there they have direct msg! :v